# hashing password using crypt and blowfish

Tags: php, mysql, passwords

i have a register page that the user enter a password so i hash this password and it being hashed in the database

but when i  try to log in it give me that the password do not match  and when i echo  it it  it do not match like i wrote a new passsword

how to fix this problem can anyone help me ???

## cryptpass function in the register

```
function cryptPass($input, $rounds = 9)
{
    $salt = "";
    $saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    for($i = 0; $i<22; $i++)
    {
        $salt  .=$saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)]; 
    }
    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
$hashedpass = cryptPass($pass1);
```

## crypt function in login

```
function cryptPass($input, $rounds = 9)
{
    $salt = "";
    $saltChars = array_merge(range('A','Z'), range('a','z'), range('0','9'));
    for($i = 0; $i<22; $i++)
    {
        $salt  .=$saltChars[array_rand($saltChars)]; 
    }
    return crypt($input, sprintf('$2y$%02d$', $rounds) . $salt);
}
$hashedpass = cryptPass($pass);   
echo $hashedpass;
```

Answer (score 1):

your password salt needs to be same when it is hashed against the stored password.  usually, a  random salt is generated by your code when the user registers/changes his/her password.  it is then stored alongside the hashed password in the database in some fashion that you can recognize it.  you then use that salt to re-hash the password when it comes time to validate the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

The salt you are adding to the password before hashing must be the same every
time.

Instead of generating a random salt I would recommend creating an arbitrary
constant that you use every time.

```
$salt = '@#$JASasdjbh&*()';
```

And, of course, you should change these characters before using them in your own script.

Comment: that's not true at all.  the salt should be randomized for every single hash created.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

`A new salt is randomly generated for each password`

Comment: Sure you can generate a new salt for every password, but you MUST use the same salt originally used to store the password when hashing the value that you are comparing. Otherwise the hashes will be different and the validation will fail

Comment: correct. password salting is ONLY useful if you use randomized hashes.  using the same salt does the same thing as using no salt at all.  the whole point is to make it harder for someone to inspect the hashed passwords and figure out the hashing algorithm

Comment: Isn't the major security concern here that someone might get a hold of the hashes stored in the database? If so, the salts would most likely be compromised as well completely negating their purpose.

Comment: salts are not used like that.  salts are used to make passwords that are the same appear different.  if two users both have the password 'apple', using both methods (no salt, and the same salt) will yield the same output.  thus, you use a random salt for every password so that 'apple' becomes two different outputs.

edit: In my second response above, I meant to say 'randomized salts', not 'randomized hashes'

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. I was under the impression that salting the hash was primarily for password obfuscation in the event that the hash was cracked, but I can see that doesn't make sense now. Thanks for clarifying!